# What should I write in my biographical statement for a paper submission if I have no prior experience?

Tags: paper-submission

I'm a high school student with no prior experience related to this field. I worked on a project over the summer with some PHD students at a lab internship and it was good enough that I can publish it as a conference paper. However, I'm at a loss on what to write for the biographical statement.

Comment: What's wrong with "Lunaarke is a senior at Rainier High School in Seattle, Washington."

Comment: They ask for a biography of several paragraphs in length.

Comment: @Lunaarke That sounds very unusual to me, I've never seen a "biography" in a paper of that length. Does the journal provide some guidance for their unusual request?

Comment: "Lunaarke is a senior at Rainier High School in Seattle, Washington. He did an internship at Awesome Labs during summer 2022, which lead to the results presented here." is your complete (and slightly impressive) biography. There is no need to fluff it just to comply with arbitrary length requirements. Also, usually these requirements specify maximum length, not minimum length.

Comment: I also guess that once anyone from the conference team reads that you are in fact a high school student with not much more to say biography wise they will be ok with a shorter than normal version.